# HTML Drop Down Menu Questions

Tags: html, search, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a customized search on my website search the year+car model

so I made this drop down list like

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://store.ijdmtoy.com/-s/146.htm">
    <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="searching" VALUE="Y">
    <p>
        <select size="1" name="Search">
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2012</option>
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2010</option>
            <option>2009</option>
            <option>2008</option>
            <option>2007</option>
            <option>2006</option>
            <option>2005</option>
            <option>2004</option>
            <option>2003</option>
            <option>2002</option>
            <option>2001</option>
            <option>2000</option>
        </select>

        <select size="1" name=" ">
            <option>TSX</option>
            <option>MDX</option>
            <option>RDX</option>
            <option>RSX</option>
            <option>NSX</option>
            <option>ZDX</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="">
    </p>
</form>
```

When I run this search, it will return

```
http://store.ijdmtoy.com/Acura-LED-Interior-Light-Bundle-Deal-s/146.htm?searching=Y&Search=2011&+=TSX
```

instead of

```
http://store.ijdmtoy.com/Acura-LED-Interior-Light-Bundle-Deal-s/146.htm?searching=Y&Search=2011+TSX
```

I want to know how can I edit this code so it will return the year+car model instead of having a & and = between them?

Comment: Can you explain why you want it that way? You'd need to do that with javascript. Also, your `name` attributes are blank for the last two elements.

Comment: My website search looks like this http://store.ijdmtoy.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=2011+TSX, therefore I want to use two drop down menu to allow customer enter 2011 and TSX and when they click on the search, it will search using these two entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for complete code. check it out **Remember line no 4th. must have correct jquery file path**
notice I have given a name to second DropDown also..

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- jquery file path-->
<script src="jquery.min.js" style="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#searchform").submit(function(e){
        // prevent to submit the form
        e.preventDefault();

        //getting values
        var searching = $(this).find('input[name="searching"]');
        var search = $(this).find('select[name="Search"]');
        var other = $(this).find('select[name="OtherVal"]');

        //getting url
        var url = $(this).attr("action");

        // changing the values as u want
        var url = url+"?searching="+searching.val()+"&Search="+search.val()+"+"+other.val();

        //redirect to new URL
        window.location.href = url;

        //return false to double sure defult values are not posting to the form
        return false;
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>          
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://store.ijdmtoy.com/-s/146.htm">
    <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="searching" VALUE="Y">
    <p>
        <select size="1" name="Search">
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2012</option>
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2010</option>
            <option>2009</option>
            <option>2008</option>
            <option>2007</option>
            <option>2006</option>
            <option>2005</option>
            <option>2004</option>
            <option>2003</option>
            <option>2002</option>
            <option>2001</option>
            <option>2000</option>
        </select>

        <select size="1" name="OtherVal">
            <option>TSX</option>
            <option>MDX</option>
            <option>RDX</option>
            <option>RSX</option>
            <option>NSX</option>
            <option>ZDX</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="">
    </p>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ur welcome.. if its working for you.. thn i would suggest you to mark it as an answer so that other people can understand its useful..!!

Answer (score 0):

I would first give your select elements some id's so you can identify them. In my code, I'll use id's of `selectYear` and `selectMake`. If you're open to using jQuery, you could do the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var year = $('#selectYear').val();
        var make = $('#selectMake').val();
        window.location.href = "http://store.ijdmtoy.com/Acura-LED-Interior-Light-Bundle-Deal-s/146.htm?searching=Y&Search=" + year + "+" + make;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have no knowledge about the jQuery at all, can you show me a sample coding with just year 2011, 2012 and car model of TSX and RSX to get this entire coding work this way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code above is all you'd need for the javascript. All you have to do is include jQuery in your `<head>` and set the `id` attributes on your `<select>` elements as I've stated.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but as you have two DropDown inside the form so it will send the two different -2 values, because you have not specified the name it doesn't mean it will concatenate the values and send as a single parameter. either change the page which accepts the value or use the jquery to concatenate the value before form submission ..

checkout the below code it will work for you..!!

```
$("#searchform").submit(function(e){
    // prevent to submit the form
    e.preventDefault();

    //getting values
    var searching = $(this).find('input[name="searching"]');
    var search = $(this).find('select[name="Search"]');
    var other = $(this).find('select[name="OtherVal"]');

    //getting url
    var url = $(this).attr("action");

    // changing the values as u want
    var url = url+"?searching="+searching.val()+"&Search="+search.val()+"+"+other.val();

    //redirect to new URL
    window.location.href = url;

    //return false to double sure defult values are not posting to the form
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Hello, Deepak Sharma, thanks for your help. Can you help me put the entire code together? Sorry I have very limited knowledge about coding. :(

Comment: no issue.. !! tell me what exactly u want..?? Please give me the url which u want on form submission.